# jQuery script not loading on production (Heroku - cedar stack)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline

I am trying to set up a modal jQuery script in my application and it works on local/development, but when I push it to heroku, the script does not work.

I viewed the html source and I think it has something to do with the asset pipeline. I have  assets compiling during slug compilation (heroku push).

Here is what the source looks like on local:

```
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/photos.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.simplemodal-1.4.3.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/pages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/photos.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/photos.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However, on production (heroku), I am only getting:

```
<link href="/assets/application-0183e1470ce8e2ba6f27e018f2b8aabf.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-20571ddeb4d7b86e69d16370f197cec1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="/assets/custom-3ab2912a0b988babf6979cc153672fe0.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is what my application.html.erb looks like:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

and my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

Any clue how I can load all my javascript/jQuery files on production?
Let me know if you guys need any additional files.

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like you have aggressive caching enabled.

Comment: You can also look in heroku logs `heroku logs --tail` will show you what's going on while you're reloading your page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried compiling assets locally?
Slug compilation seems unstable to me (it hates bootstrap).

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

git add public/assets

git commit -m "vendor compiled assets"
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar